# If $2 < a_n < 3 \ \text{for every} \ n, \ \text{then} \ \sqrt[n]{a_n} \to 1.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove that if

$$2 < a_n < 3 \ \text{for every} \ n, \ \text{then} \ \sqrt[n]{a_n} \to 1.$$

I'm assuming that this statement is not always true, i.e. not every bounded sequence has this property.

Comment: It's true for every positive bounded sequence, if both bounds are stricly positives. Use exponentials.

Comment: Define $b_n=2$ and $c_n=3$, and prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{b_n}=1$ and that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{c_n}=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is true. We have that
$$
2^{1/n}<a_n^{1/n}<3^{1/n}
$$
for each $n$. It follows that
$$
\frac1n\log 2<\log (a_n^{1/n})<\frac1n\log 3
$$
and we obtain
$$
\log(a_n^{1/n})\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Using the continuity of the function $x\mapsto\exp\{x\}$, we conclude that
$$
a_n^{1/n}=\exp\{\log(a_n^{1/n})\}\to\exp\{0\}=1
$$
as $n\to\infty$.